# Jetty's HTTP/2 client slow?

Tags: jetty, http2

Doing simple GET requests over a high speed internet connection (within an AWS EC2 instance), the throughput seems to be really low. I've tried this with multiple servers.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```java
HTTP2Client http2Client = new HTTP2Client();
http2Client.start();
SslContextFactory ssl = new SslContextFactory(true);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(http2Client), ssl);
client.start();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      System.out.println("i" + i);
      ContentResponse response = client.GET("https://http2.golang.org/");
      System.out.println(response.getStatus());
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

The throughput I get is about 8 requests per second.

This seems to be pretty low (as compared to curl on the command line).

Is there anything that I'm missing? Any way to turbo-charge this?

**EDIT:** How do I get Jetty to use multiple streams?

Comment: making synchronous requests seems very counter productive and isn't using HTTP/2's powers at all. You want N transfers going on in parallel!

Comment: Exactly my point. So how do I tell that to Jetty? Use 100 streams and use them all?

Comment: Then maybe the question should've included that! =)

Comment: Added it to end of my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the right way to measure throughput.

Depending where you are geographically, you will be dominated by the latency between your client and the server. If the latency is 125 ms, you can only make 8 requests/s. 
For example, from my location, the `ping` to http2.golang.org is 136 ms.

Even if your latency is less, there are good chances that the server is throttling you: I don't think that http2.golang.org will be happy to see you making 10k requests in a tight loop.

I'll be curious to know what is the `curl` or `nghttp` latency in the same test, but I guess won't be much different (or probably worse if they close the connection after each request).

[This test](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/tests/test-http-client-transport/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/client/HttpClientLoadTest.java) in the Jetty test suite, which is not a proper benchmark either, shows around 500 requests/s on my laptop; without TLS, goes to around 2500 requests/s.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but your test does not tell you anything about the performance of Jetty's `HttpClient`.

Comment: So http2.golang.org is just my example. I'm trying to write a HTTP/2 library for the Apple push notification gateway - which will definitely not throttle me (as the docs claim that I should be able to make hundreds per second). The ping round trip is 113ms from the EC2 instance I'm on, but I'm assuming that if you keep the connection open, it should be able to do far more. In a previous single threaded benchmark using Apache's HTTP components, I could do 1k+ easily on a HTTP website.

Comment: Is there any way I can tell Jetty to create 10 streams and use them?

Comment: sbordet: right, doing synchronous single-shot transfers like that will be equally bad with any other client.

Comment: @judepereira your test is synchronous: makes a request, waits for the response, then loops and makes another request, waits for the response and so on. This is because you are using the HttpClient.GET() API, which is synchronous. Whether you keep the connection open or not, you are dominated by the ping latency because you do synchronous single requests in a single threaded loop.

Comment: @judepereira if you want to use asynchronous API, please [read the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client-api.html). I guess your Apache "benchmark" was asynchronous, otherwise it's impossible to get 1k+ requests over WAN. You want to use the asynchronous APIs in the Jetty `HttpClient` too.

Comment: @sbordet, you're right. I wasn't using the async API. I did use the async API, however, I was on 9.3.6, and had faced the slow issue (due to a bug). Since I upgraded to 9.3.7, I hadn't tested the async. Thanks a lot :)